# Filter unique custom field value based on custom taxonomy category or other custom field

Tags: php, custom-field, taxonomy

Is there an easy way to obtain a list of uniqye custom fields value from a specified taxonomy value?

For example, I have many categories under taxonomy "products". Every product has some custom fields, for example: "color", that I use to build a  tag with a list of available product colors.

When i select a product category (f. ex. "Cars"), I wish to filter out the colors that are NOT included in the selected category. In other words, if NO car is brown, "Brown" (though it is a value that is present in other product categories) should not be listed.

The same thing should happen when I select another custom field value (f. ex., "year" on "2010". If no product of year 2010 is "red", "red" should be filtered out).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The filtering can be done with this function **totally untested**

```
function filter_custom_fields($key='', $terms='', $tax='', $selkey='', $selval='') {
   global $wpdb;
   $include = '';
   if ( $selkey && $selval && ( is_string($selval) || is_array($selval) ) ) {
     $include = " AND post_id IN (" . 
                 $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                 WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value ", $selkey );
     if ( is_array($selval) ) {
        $selvals = '';
        foreach ( $selval as $val ) {
            if ( $selvals != '' ) $selvals .= ',';
            $selvals .= $wpdb->prepare('%s', $val);
        }
        $include .= "IN ($selvals))";
     } else {
        $include .= $wpdb->prepare( "= %s)", $selval );
     }
   }
   if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) { 
      if ( is_array($terms) ) {
        $terms = array_map('intval', $terms );
        $ttis = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM 
                $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE 
                term_id IN (" . implode(',', $terms ) . ")");
        if ($ttis) {
          $include .= " AND post_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_id
             FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE
             term_taxonomy_id IN (" . implode(',', $ttis) . "))";
          }
      } else {        
        $field = is_numeric($terms) ? 'id' : 'slug';
        $term_obj = get_term_by( $field, $terms, $tax);
        if ( $term_obj && ! is_wp_error($term_obj) ) {
           $include .= ' AND post_id IN (' . $wpdb->prepare(
             "SELECT DISTINCT object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE
             term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term_obj->term_taxonomy_id
           ) . ")";
        }
      }
   }
   $query = $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s",
            $key);
   if ( $include ) $query .= $include;
   $meta = $wpdb->get_col($query); 
   if ( $meta ) return array_map('maybe_unserialize', $meta);
}
```

As asked, the function above can

- filter out a custom field by a taxonomy term
- filter out a custom field by a another custom field

But can do more:

- filter out by more than one taxonomy term
- filter out by more than one custom field
- filter out by more than one taxonomy term by another custom field
- filter out by a taxonomy term and by more than one custom field
- filter out by more than one taxonomy term and by more than one custom field

Moreover, function gives you flexibility to choose the taxonomy: one custom tax as you asked, or category or post...

How use it:

### Filtering by a taxonomy term

```
$cars_colors = filter_custom_fields('color', 'cars', 'products');
```

Third param is for taxonomy, so you can use with taxonomy you need. Note that you have to use term slug or term id and *not* term name.

### Filtering by another custom field

```
$colors_2010 = filter_custom_fields('color', false, false, 'year', '2010');
```

Self explanatory, I think.

### Filtering by a taxonomy term and by another custom field

```
$cars_colors_2010 = filter_custom_fields('color', 'cars', 'products', 'year', '2010');
```

### Filtering by multiple taxonomy term

```
$cars_and_moto_colors = filter_custom_fields('color', array(12,13), 'products');
```

### Filtering by multiple values of another custom field

```
$colors_2009_2010_2011 = filter_custom_fields('color', false, false, 'year', array('2009', '2010', '2011'));
```

### Filtering by multiple taxonomy term and multiple values of another custom field

```
$cars_and_moto_colors_2009_2010_2011 = filter_custom_fields('color', array(12,13), 'products', 'year', arary('2009', '2010', '2011'));
```

---

Just a note. You wrote nothing about post types. This function works *not* taking into accounts post types, so if custom field and/or taxonomy you want to filter by are assigned to different post types it may not work as expected.

Hope it helps (and hope it works).